# caret::train pass extra parameters rpart

Tags: r, r-caret, cp, rpart

I'm building a decision tree with rpart via the caret::train function. What I'm trying to do is to set the minsplit parameter of rpart equal to 1, in order to prune it afterwards with the cp. What I get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366174/carettrain-specify-further-non-tuning-parameters-for-mlpweightdecay-rsnns-pa) is that the parameters should be passed in the ... of the train function. But this doesn't work. A minimal reproducible example:

```
mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., iris, method = "rpart", tuneGrid = expand.grid(cp = 0), minsplit=1)
mod2 <- rpart(Species ~ ., iris, cp=0, minsplit=1)
```

What I get is that mod1$finalModel and mod2 are quite different. I would like that mod1$finalModel was like mod2 (i.e., totally overfitted). I cannot pass the parameter either on the tuneGrid since it only accepts a cp column.

So my question is: is there anyway in caret to pass the argument minsplit=1 in the train function and then cross validate over the cp parameter?

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625493/tuning-two-parameters-for-random-forest-in-caret-package/38633939#38633939). Handing `rpart` should be similar.

Comment: Could you try this: `mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., iris, method = "rpart", control = list(cp=0), minsplit=1);identical(mod1$finalModel$splits,mod2$splits)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, thanks [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781755/how-to-specify-minbucket-in-caret-train-for) I figured out how to do it:

```
mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., iris, method = "rpart", 
             control = rpart.control(minsplit = 1, minbucket = 1))
```

I'm still not quite sure why the argument has to be passed via control = rpart.control(). Passing just the arguments minsplit = 1, minbucket = 1 directly to the train function simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that ‘control = rpart.control()’ is necessary for passing the arguments ‘minsplit’ and ‘minbucket’ within {caret} train-function as this would be the correct way in the rpart-function itself, to which the arguments are sent via  ‘...’ of the {caret} train-function.
Best, G